# Image and dropdown not line up

Tags: html, css, styles

[image]

Currently I have some image links and a dropdown. However, the images are higher than dropdown, how can I make them line up?

```
<a id="nextid" href="javascript:PrePage()"><img src="/graphics/newIcons/previous.png" style = "height: 19px; width: 19px;" title = "Next"></img></a>
<a id="preid" href="javascript:PreCommentPage()"><img src="/graphics/newIcons/previous.png" style = "height: 19px; width: 19px;" title = "Next"></img></a>  
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="saab">General Comments  -4 comments(s)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a `div` container, and use flexbox, like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a id="nextid" href="javascript:PrePage()"><img src="/graphics/newIcons/previous.png" style="height: 19px; width: 19px;" title="Next"></img>
  </a>
  <a id="preid" href="javascript:PreCommentPage()"><img src="/graphics/newIcons/previous.png" style="height: 19px; width: 19px;" title="Next"></img>
  </a>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="saab">General Comments -4 comments(s)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `vertical-align: middle` property in your img tags

```css
#nextid, #preid {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<a id="nextid" href="javascript:PrePage()"><img src="/graphics/newIcons/previous.png" style = "height: 19px; width: 19px;" title = "Next"></img></a>
<a id="preid" href="javascript:PreCommentPage()"><img src="/graphics/newIcons/previous.png" style = "height: 19px; width: 19px;" title = "Next"></img></a>  
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="saab">General Comments  -4 comments(s)</option>
</select>
```